# Updating a table within a Zend view based on an AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

My webapp has a view which displays a table (html table) at the bottom.
I need to display some of the data in the table in a different format depending on a select element and an AJAX response.  It basically relates to timezones.

I have lots of JSON AJAX in my webapp which are all working fine.

But with this particular aspect I'm really confused.  I've tried loads of things.

Here's a summary:
-  The select element has an onchange which runs some javascript
-  The javascript runs two AJAX calls, one for JSON and one for HTML (shown below)

```
    $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                type: "POST",
                data: {timzone_option:option,lo_id:lo_id},
                dataType:'HTML',
                success: function(response) 
                {
        $('#c-content').html(data);
                } //end success

    });
```

- The JSON one works fine, the HTML one doesn't do anything
- The URL being called, triggers a function within a Controller, which does the following:

  ```
  $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
  $option_id = $this->_getParam('timzone_option');
      $in_lo_id = $this->_getParam('lo_id'); 

  $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
  global $objSession;
  if($this->view->user->user_id!='')
  {
          $recC = $this->modelSuper->Selectcallprod("CALL SP_GET_C_VIA_O('".$in_lo_id."')",'fetchall');
          $list_tmzn = getVal('timezones','zone_name', 'zone_id', $recC['listing_timezone']) ;
          $user_tmzn = getVal('timezones','zone_name', 'zone_id', $this->view->user->user_timezone_id) ;     
          if($option_id == 1)
              {
          $numCount=0;
          foreach($recC as $record) 
          {
              $recC[$numCount]['loc_deadline_date']=convertUserDate($record['loc_deadline_date'], $this->view->user->user_datetimeformat, $list_tmzn,'UTC');
              $numCount++;
          }
              }
              if($option_id == 2)
              {
          $numCount=0;
          foreach($recC as $record) 
          {
              $recC[$numCount]['loc_deadline_date']=convertUserDate($record['loc_deadline_date'], $this->view->user->user_datetimeformat, $user_tmzn,'UTC');
              $numCount++;
          }
              }
      $this->view->c = $recC;
  } else
  die();
  echo $recC;
  exit();
  ```

My question is even though I've referred to the divid correctly, how is Zend/PHP expected to know how to "inject" the AJAX response (which is an array being the recordset to display in the table) into the table nicely?  I've tried changing the dataType from HTML to JSON and neither makes any difference.

I've verified that my SQL stored procedure syntax and parameters are fine, the javascript is executing but the results aren't flowing back to the view as I want them to.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case of ajax `$this->view->c` will not work. Use the json way and simply `echo json_encode($recC)`. Now you will be able to get response in javascript. Just add `console.log(data)` in your success block.

Comment: I tried that but no joy unfortunately.  I've now got my code to the point where the controller has an array containing the values returned from the ajax call, I just need to pass the results to an ajax view in Zend and I'm done.

Comment: Please update your code on SO. Have you checked your output in firbug console.

Answer (score 0):

My original Javascript was fine, the problem was with the receiving action within the controller.

I changed:
                $list_tmzn = getVal('timezones','zone_name', 'zone_id', $recC['listing_timezone']) ;

to:
                $list_tmzn = getVal('timezones','zone_name', 'zone_id', $recC[0]['listing_timezone']) ;

I improved both foreach blocks to improve null handling.

Lastly I created a receiving Zend view with the same name as the action.

At that point I could see my content.  I had to tidy up the ajax view a bit but it's now working really nicely.